# Difference Between request.status and request.statusCode

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am learning AJAX and I wanna know the difference between the request.status and request.statusCode functions.

for example:

```
document.getElementById('erroDv').innerHTML = request.status;
document.getElementById('erroDv').innerHTML = request.statusCode;
```

Thanks in advance!

Dwarak

Comment: Where did you find `request.statusCode`? It's nowhere in the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/). Also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest#Properties

Answer (score 1):

- `status` contains the numerical code, like 200 or 404
- `statusText` contains the corresponding text, like "OK" or "Not Found"

[Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-status-attribute)

Comment: How about the function request.statusCode?

Comment: The OP is asking about a property named "statusCode" not "statusText", although you may actually still be right that one is the code and one is the textual description.